iOS 18, Safari Extension tabs.sendMessage not working
I'm using sendMessage to send a message to the content script of a specific tab, identified by its tabId. However, in iOS 18 Safari, the message is being sent to all tabs instead of just the targeted one. The code works fine in iOS 17.
browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {'message'});
The code works fine in iOS 17.
